# Wordpress query in which condition uses custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, loop

I have a query for custom post type as follow:

```
`$args = array('post_type' => 'interviews', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'paged' => $paged);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);`
```

In my each interview post i have repeater value which returns only 1 value every time.
I want to select those interview post which have particular repeater value only ...How can i write the query.
I tried metakey and metanum value but dint work.
In my post meta db metakey is 'speakers_0_speakers_relation' and meta value is '**a:1:{i:0;s:2:"76";}**'. please help me

Answer (score 0):

You're already on the right track, you just need to add the meta key and meta value args to the query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'interviews', 
    'posts_per_page' => 6, 
    'post_status'    => 'publish', 
    'paged'          => $paged
    'meta_key'       => 'speakers_0_speakers_relation',
    'meta_value'     => '76'
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```